# Delete file using ajax laravel (404 error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax to delete a file, but it showed 404 error.
I checked route again but i don't know where is wrong!
Any solution?
Thanks so much!

[image]

**My Route**

`Route::post('/deleteFile/ajax/{id}', 'DproductController@deleteFileAjax')->name('delete.file.ajax');`

**My Controller**

```
public function deleteFileAjax($id)
{
    if (allow('delete') == true) {
        $deleteFile = DproductFile::find($id);
        $deleteFile->delete();
        return response()->json('message', 'Yes');
    } else {
        return response()->json('message', 'No');
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{ $dproductFile->id }}" name="{{ $dproductFile->filename }}" link="{{ route('delete.file.ajax', $dproductFile->id) }}" class="deleteClick red id-btn-dialog2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">
                                                            <span class="btn-sm btn btn-danger"><i title="Delete" class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></span></a>

// ajax
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         }
     });

            $('.deleteClick').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/deleteFile/ajax/' + id,
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('OK');
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: do you have any prefix in your route?? and try with absolute route instead of relative route.

Comment: 404 route is not found . Can you check the route  please?

Comment: zahidhasanemon, No, I haven't. What is absolute route? I don't understand

Comment: @hemant, I checked again and i don't know where is wrong :(

Comment: Please check once manually with the given route url.
for example: http://coredev.com:8080/deleteFile/ajax/95
Is this works?!

Comment: `<form id="deleteForm" action="" method="POST"></form>` my form

Comment: @KarthikSWOT, yes, it still works. File was deleted but ajax not working

Comment: is your `a` tag inside a `form`??

Comment: If you look at that `<a>` element in your browser's dev tools, what is the value of the `link` attribute? Try using `url: $(this).attr('link')` instead to make sure you're using the configured route by name

Comment: I use js to get action attribute, because i'm using modal to delete, and it It works normally

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and show us the result for that route. Also, for laravel post routes, you have to add a parameter with key `_token` and the csrf token as value, or it will not work

Comment: named route for the url and _token parameter should work: `url: '{{ route('delete.file.ajax') }}', data:{ _token:'{{ csrf_token() }}' },`

Answer (score 3):

You're using [Laravel named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes) `->name('delete.file.ajax')`.

So in AJAX

```
var path = "{{ route('delete.file.ajax') }}";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: path,
```

**Personally recommended to use (URL)**

```
Route::post('/deleteFile/ajax/{id}', 'DproductController@deleteFileAjax')->name('delete-file');
```

In AJAX

```
var path = "{{ route('delete-file') }}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the route again with command `php artisan route:list`.

If everything is fine with the `route` paths, you may have route caching issue.
Do clear `route` cache with `php artisan route:clear` command.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that route name is the same you used

Type

php artisan route:list

and look at route name

Answer (score 0):

Check for your `$.ajax`. `type: 'post'` will not send an ajax request as a POST request. You have to use `method: 'POST'` instead. Check the documentation for more customization - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Also from the same documentation... _"**type** (default: `'GET'`) - An alias for `method`"_